# puting combobox inside a grid makes selected item empty

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, combobox, uwp

I have two comboboxes that I would to show besides each other.
I am using a grid, and two columns for this... but when I do this, the initialliy selected item for the comboxbox disappears

so, if I put them in a grid... i get this:
[image]

If I remove the grid... the combobox gets the initial value...
the xaml looks like this... here with the grid part commented out... I just don't get why adding/removing the grid makes a difference...

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.LoadErrorMessage, Mode=OneWay}" />

        <!--<Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>-->
            <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.WeaponCountRange}" SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.WeaponCount, Mode=TwoWay}"></ComboBox>
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Weapons}" SelectedItem="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedWeapon, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Background="Black">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageFile}" Stretch="Uniform" Height="48"></Image>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Yellow" Height="48" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                                <Image VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="{Binding ShieldPiercingVis}" Height="12" Source="/Assets/ship_modules/dragon_missile.png"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        <!--</Grid>-->
        <Border>
```

[image]

the code behind that populates, is a async task... see the following

```
public ObservableCollection<WeaponViewModel> Weapons = new ObservableCollection<WeaponViewModel>();
private WeaponViewModel _selectedWeapon;
public WeaponViewModel SelectedWeapon
{
    get => _selectedWeapon;
    set => SetProperty(ref _selectedWeapon, value);
}
private async Task Initialize()
    {
        {
            var wRepo = new WeaponRepository();
            await wRepo.Initialize();
            foreach (var item in wRepo.Weapons)
            {
                Weapons.Add(new WeaponViewModel(item));
                if (Weapons.Count == 1)
                    SelectedWeapon = Weapons[0];
            }
        }
    ...
```

Comment: Why would you define your gui in such a way in the world of modern winforms?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your issue. When I run your code, it throw exception. And I found that you have not set `IValueConverter` for `SelectedItem`. I have created the converter for `SelectedItem` and it works well in my side. I will upload the [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/CommboxInGrid905.git) that you could refer to.

**Converter**

```
public class Converter : IValueConverter
 {
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
     {
         return value;

     }

     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
     {
         return value as ComboBoxItem;
     }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: I tested your sample, and you are right, it doesn't have the same problem. Regarding the Object Converter, I don't know what it is normaly used for (just started with UWP), but it can be removed if TargetPlatformMinVersion is changed from 10.0.10586.0 to 10.0.15063.0, after this I got stack overflow in the property setter, fixed by changing if the value was changed. non the less. I have made a [branch of your code that works without the converter](https://github.com/buildcomplete/CommboxInGrid905)

Comment: [My code](https://github.com/buildcomplete/orion-datasheets) still that have the problem, right now the problmematic part is commented out, but in lives in Views/WeaponAnalysisView.xaml

Comment: I have clone your project, but it lost a lot of asset files,  Could you share me how to get them(`%steamapps%\common\Master of Orion\MasterOfOrion_Data\StreamingAssets\assets\empire_management`).

Comment: I'm afraid they are copyrighted :/, they are part of [Master Of Orion](http://store.steampowered.com/app/298050/Master_of_Orion/)